# Unity FBX goes through every object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm learning how to use mecanim and followed a tutorial using the Raw Mocap animation set from the unity store. But the default rig would walk through cubes and fall through the plane. I've added colliders to the cube and plane but it still wouldn't work. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a little vague, as you've given us so little to work with. It could be caused by many things - can you include screenshots of your scene hierarchy and relevant components so we understand your situation better, and how you're approaching the problem?

Answer (score 0):

your character should have colliders too and if it has a rigidbody component attached  to it set `IsTrigger=false` and it it has player controller attached to it it will only collide if the other object has player controller too